# Add value before query params via interceptor

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, interceptor

I have an id, which I should add to each url's path, which I did via interceptor.

```
val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
newRequest.url(chain.request().url.toString() + "/" + id)
return chain.proceed(newRequest.build())
```

Problems occur with the first endpoint with query parameters. So with this code I got

```
MY_BASE_URL?query_param_1=value1&query_param_2=value2/ID
```

but it should be

```
MY_BASE_URL/ID?query_param_1=value1&query_param_2=value2
```

Any good idea how to solve this?

P.S.

There is a hacky solution, but would like to have something better.

```
newRequest.url(chain.request().url.toString().replace("?", "/" + userId.toString() + "?", true))
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpUrl has several methods for obtaining the specific parts of the URL, such as host, path and query. You could do something like

```
val url = chain.request().url
val newUrl = url.scheme()+"://"+url.host()+url.encodedPath()+"/"+userId.toString()
```

with url.query() appended to the end if there is one. Consider also adding url.port() and url.encodedFragment() if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the HttpUrl into a Builder which you can manipulate.

```
val newUrl = chain.request().url
    .newBuilder()
    .addPathSegment("ID")
    .build()
val newRequest = chain.request()
    .newBuilder()
    .url(newUrl)
    .build()
chain.proceed(newRequest)
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but will not work when I have path parameters. my id will appear at the end of url, when I need that before path parameters as well